# Why my blog with Jekyll Bootstrap not update?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I push it several hours ago, but my blog didn't changed yet.
Does github.com server delay or my personal reason? It test will in my computer with `localhost:4000`.

PS: So, I delete the repo and recreate the repo in github, but 404 always:-(

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing the page via username.github.com, or at a personal domain?

If it's at a personal domain, make sure you have a CNAME file (with that name) in the foot of the repo. It should just contain this: `www.myfancydomain.com`. Check your [DNS settings](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages) as well.

If you're using any plugins, GitHub won't run them during generation. That could be causing a problem?

Also make sure the pushed site is in the gh-pages branch. Always good to check the basics. :)